# Pass url as parameter in django rest get method best practice

Tags: parameters, get, django-rest-framework

Please provide me url path pattern, so I can provide endpoint which accepts requests as in example .

*/urlupload/?url=http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg&type=jpeg*
I know that the following url pattern

```
path('^urlupload/$', views.UrlUpload.as_view()),
url = request.GET['url']
type = request.GET['type']
```

fetches the appropriate requests, but for my swagger documentation I want to pass parameters explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

url is a query param. You can access to a query param like this

```
url_str = self.request.query_params.get('url')
type_str = self.request.query_params.get('type')
```

You do not need change path pattern